# Use _GET URL as video source

Tags: php, url, video, get

Basically I have the following code that will get a video based on its id value.

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
   $id = $_GET["id"];
   $video = "vid" . $id;
   echo "<video controls><source src='{$video}' type='video/mp4'></video>";
     } else {
       echo "File not found.";
   }
?>
```

So if you go to http://www.animesour.com/video.php?id=555.mp4 , the video called vid555.mp4 will load (which works).

However when I try to load that URL in this code it won't load the video.

```
<video tabindex="0" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://www.animesour.com/video.php?id=555.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Anyone know how to make it so that this will work?

Comment: You should escape $_GET['id']: http://www.animesour.com/video.php?id='><script>alert('xss')</script>

Comment: @JimL Sorry, I don't quite follow what you said, could you revise the code?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

Answer (score 0):

You need load the video directly when you directly embed as src, because your code adds such output that makes the second option incorrect, for example:

The url to direct video is: http://www.animesour.com/vid555.mp4

```
<video tabindex="0" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://www.animesour.com/vid555.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

If you still want to use `video.php?id=555.mp4` then you need to change your PHP to read the file for streaming.

Comment: How might I do that, because streaming is the result I want.

Comment: Anyway to stream using the id=55?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have as the source isn't the source.  It's a link to a script that will load the source.  Instead of making that the source, it needs to point to the place in your file structure that has the video.  Therefore, you need to build the structure in your code and echo that out to the markup.

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
       $id = $_GET["id"];
       $video = "vid" . $id;
       echo "<video tabindex=\"0\" controls=\"controls\">";
       echo "<source src=\"{$video}\" type=\"video/mp4\">";
       echo "</video>";
   } else {
       echo "File not found.";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code, and neither works for me (visiting the URL you posted, or using the url as source)

The video player appears on both, but the video plays on neither.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to do it. I just changed the first code to

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$file = "vid" . $id . ".mp4";

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
?>
```

I can now link it externally in an iframe with a URL with the ?id=555 and it will load the video file into the player.